# Collapsible Menu With Fixed Width Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.menu {
 max-width: 350px;
 margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <title>Booting the mind with Bootstrap</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical menu">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block menuitem" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Apple</button>
       <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        Hello world! I am Raj. I am trying to make something. But I don't know if I could do that.
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default menuitem">Samsung</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default menuitem">Sony</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to create a collapsible button menu having a fixed initial width using Bootstrap. I want this menu to be responsive. By setting the ***width*** of the button group, I am being able to get a menu with a perfect width. However, I am loosing its responsive property. By replacing the ***width*** property in the CSS file with the ***max-width*** property, I am getting a responsive menu. But then the width of the menu is changing when a menu item is expanded and collapsed. I also tried to set the ***width***, ***max-width*** and ***min-width*** of ***.btn*** class. But all these trials went in vain. Is there any way through which I can achieve both responsiveness and a fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.menu {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .menu{
    width:25%;
  }
}
```

sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36942/)..